# Передача параметров в шаблонах по значению и по ссылке

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пишу шаблон функции:

```
template <class T> void fun(T tt){
//здесь какая-то работа с tt
}
```

Теперь хочу, чтобы если тип T маленький, то чтобы при инстанцировании параметр передавался по значению:

```
void fun(little_struct tt){
//здесь какая-то работа с tt
}
```

А если если тип T большой, то чтобы при инстанцировании параметр передавался по ссылке:

```
void fun(big_struct& tt){
//здесь какая-то работа с tt
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли так сделать в С++ (чтобы транслятор сам определял размер параметра и соответственно инстанцировал шаблон).
2. Если можно, то как? И как тогда указать критерий для размера параметра, после которого параметр будет передаваться по ссылке?

Comment: не, такое поведение не предусмотрено

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вариант с одной функцией](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e93c8511d0a0fd8)

```
template<class T>
void foo(typename std::conditional_t<(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*)) && std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>, T, const T&> arg)
{
}
```

Но так компилятор не может вывести `T`. Мне на ум не приходит как это разрешить при помощи шаблонов. Так что могу предложить вам писать

```
foo<Type>(arg)
```

или сделать макрос

```
#define foo(arg) foo_impl<decltype(arg)>(arg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Так не годится?

```
template<typename T, typename = enable_if_t<sizeof(T) <= 2>>
void f(T)
{
    cout << "By value\n";
};


template<typename T, typename = enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) > 2)>>
void f(const T&)
{
    cout << "By reference\n";
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    f(short(3));
    f(3);
}
```

Можно поиграться в игру `conditional`

```
template<typename T>
    void f(typename conditional_t<sizeof(T) <= 2,T,const T&> t)
{
    if (is_reference_v<decltype(t)>)
        cout << "By reference\n";
    else
        cout << "By value\n";
};
```

но тогда надо явно указывать тип при вызове -

```
f<short>(3);
f<int>(3);
```

Что-то в голове вертится, как обойти... но никак не доверчивается :), а другой работы хватает. Если подсознание само решит проблему :) - допишу.

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы обработка была одинаковая и не нужно было бы повторять два раза тело функции. Не писать же тело функции в виде макроса.

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: Будет некорректно работать со структурами, в которых динамически аллоцируется память, т.е. почти со всеми контейнерами и т.п.

Comment: @Drawn Raccoon Вопрос конечно интересный, но про динамические контейнеры речи пока что не идет. Шаблоны это механизм времени компиляции, с ним бы разобраться, хотя бы для тех типов, размер которых известен на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @Harry Тип при вызове можно и указать, труд невелик. Будем ждать, когда подсознание сработает.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя менять тип и при этом сохранять deducible context (т.е. не указывать тип при вызове). Но в С++ почти всё, что не решается напрямую, решается косвенным образом. Поэтому нужно просто ввести один уровень косвенности. Вашу функцию с кодом мы немного переименуем и будет она выглядеть так:

```
template <class T> void fun_impl(T tt) 
{
    //...
}
```

А теперь напишем вспомогательную функцию, которая за нас сделает всю необходимую работу:

```
template <class T> void fun(T&& tt)
{
    using Pure_t = std::decay_t<T>;
    constexpr bool isBig = sizeof(T) > 16;
    if constexpr(isBig)
        fun_impl<Pure_t&>(tt);
    else
        fun_impl<Pure_t>(tt);
}
```

Вот и всё. Можно добавить ещё пачку булевых переменных, чтобы охватить вектора, строки и прочее — всё это добавляется элементарно.

P.S. Я надеюсь, что интерес тут сугубо академический, потому что в подобном разграничении нет никакого смысла. Подобным функциям не место в реальном коде.

Comment: [Подобным функциям не место в реальном коде.] Ну почему же не место? Если уж биться за эффективность, то на всех фронтах. В том числе и оптимизируя передачу параметров в функцию. Тем более, если все решения принимаются во время компиляции и в рантайме нет потерь производительности.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 потому что если выигрыш в производительности и будет (в чём я сильно сомневаюсь), то он будет ничтожным в 99.999999% случаев. А вот написать подобную функцию правильно и понятно — достаточно сложно.

Comment: @ixSci, так ведь `fun` уже получил значение по ссылке. Драгоценные такты и байты уже потеряны, смысла полбарасывать аргумент дальше уже нет

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb эту функцию-обёртку компилятор просто выкинет, её не будет в коде.