# Есть ли реальные основания для передачи маленьких объектов через копию, а не по ссылке?

Tags: c++

Я несколько раз слышал о том, что маленькие объекты, которые могут быть размещены в 2-3 регистрах, стоит передавать в виде копии, а не по ссылке. В пользу этого приводится невнятное объяснение о том, что так рекомендуется в **каком-то** гайде от разработчиков компиляторов (или для разработчиков компиляторов).

Иногда данная рекомендация развивается дальше, упоминая о том, что процессор также может оптимизировать выполнение, путем исключения обратной записи объекта в память, если он не менялся.

Мне не удалось найти никакой информации по этой теме.

Может быть, кто-нибудь сможет пояснить данный вопрос или подсказать источник, в котором содержится данная рекомендация?

Comment: Ну ведь важна же не только передача, но еще и работа с ними в функции, а по ссылке - это постоянные разыменования...

Comment: думаю будет полезно почитать и http://scrutator.me/post/2018/07/30/value_vs_reference.aspx

Comment: @Harry - я правильно понимаю - разыменование ссылки?

Comment: @KoVadim Естественно, не явное, от вас никто звездочку не потребует писать. Но на практике будет передан указатель на объект, который будет разыменовываться неявно.

Comment: Что-то подобное на SO-ru уже обсуждали, но внятного решения не нашлось: [Передача параметров в шаблонах по значению и по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003799/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5)

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Добавить что угодно не сложно, но учить и главное помнить команды ручного форматирования html это слишком. Поверьте, и без того есть чем заняться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Передача по значению - создается копия, как вы сами говорите, возможно, в регистре. Т.е если объект маленький, размером с указатель - то его копирование стоит стоко же, что и указетеля.

Когда работаете со ссылкой, на самом деле передаетмся адрес объекта, т.е указатель. Разницы к объеме работы никакой.

Но при работе дополнительно приходится разыменовывать это указатель, так что это лишняя работа. Если ее не уменьшит как-то оптимизатор.

Если надо менять переданный в функцию аргумент, то выбора у вас нет, тут только по ссылке.